# Problems with extracting a line with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file where the data is in the following format:

> Cl    -2.30000000     0.00000000     0.00000000
>
> Mn     0.00000000     0.00000000     0.00000000
>
> Cl     2.30000000     0.00000000     0.00000000
>
> ...

And so on for many more lines. I need to extract this data line by line and write them to another file. I am using the following code to test what I am doing:

```
ABC=$(sed -n "6 s/[A-Z]//p" $XYZ)

echo $ABC
```

where XYZ is the filename. However, the output I am getting is as follows(as an example):

> 0.00000000 0.00000000 -2.20000000

That is, the letters at the beginning are not printing. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening, and how to resolve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: You are doing a search and replace with sed. `s/[A-Z]//` means you are searching for A-Z and replace them with empty string.

Comment: That's what the 6 s/[A-Z]//p part does. What did you actually intend to do ? (Note also that you might run into all kinds of issues with newlines when you store the result in a shell variable and use echo on it - you should perhaps just redirect the sed output to a file)

Comment: If you just want to read the file line by line, use `read` with a while loop. `while read -r line; do echo $line; done < filename`

Comment: `I need to extract this data line by line and write them to another file.` That just means you have to copy one file to another..

Comment: How about `cut -d ' ' -f 2- YourFile` to set the field separator to a space and print field 2 onwards?

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont know what exactly you are trying to achieve.
Lets say the data file is data.txt and the target is appendto.txt

If you need to Read the data of one file and append it to an other.

```
cat data.txt >> appendto.txt
```

If you need to change the order of columns of your data.

```
sed -n 's/^\([A-Z].*\) \([-0-9].*\.[0-9].*\) \([-0-9].*\.[0-9].*\) \([-0-9].*\.[0-9].*\)$/\2 \3 \4 \1/p' data.txt >> appendto.txt
```

if you like to use it in a script to manipulate your data even further.

```
cat data.txt | while read line
do
    col1=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    col2=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
    col3=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
    col4=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 4)

    # Manipulte data
    # And append it
    echo $col2 $col4 $col1 $col3 >> appendto.txt
done
```

sure you could also use sed, but it seams to be a bit of an overhead in this script.

```
cat data.txt | while read line                   
do                                               
    col1=$(echo $line | sed -n 's/^\([A-Z].*\) .*$/\1/p')
    col2=$(echo $line | sed -n 's/^[A-Z].* \([-0-9].*\.[0-9].*\) .*$/\1/p')
    col3=$(echo $line | sed -n 's/^[A-Z].* [-0-9].*\.[0-9].* \([-0-9].*\.[0-9].*\) .*$/\1/p')
    col4=$(echo $line | sed -n 's/^[A-Z].* [-0-9].*\.[0-9].* [-0-9].*\.[0-9].* \([-0-9].*\.[0-9].*\)$/\1/p')

    # Manipulte data                             
    # And append it                              
    echo $col2 $col4 $col1 $col3 >> appendto.txt                                                                                                        
done
```